# Python complains of missing dictionary value

Tags: python

I built a script using Python that lists all aws instances in an account.

The script works, except when it encounters an instance that doesn't have any tags.

I tried to account for that using these lines:

```
# Test for the existance of tags
if instance['Tags']:
    tags = instance['Tags']
    try:
        for tag in tags:
            if tag["Key"] == "Name":
                name = tag["Value"]
    except ValueError:
        print("No tags on instance ",instance["InstanceId"])
```

And yet the error persists:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 180, in <module>
    loop_regions()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 90, in loop_regions
    if instance['Tags']:
KeyError: 'Tags'
```

If I comment out all the lines pertaining to Tags, and set a static value for 'name' the script works perfecty! However I do need to grab the name tag.

This is the json representation of an instance: [ec2_instance_json](https://pastebin.com/Vym3tZTj)

What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly create an exception if the Tags don't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Boolean setting, `instance['Tags']` is true if the *value* is true, not if the key exists. You want `if 'Tags' in instance:` instead.